# bash completion in terminal - files vs folders

Tags: bash

I just recently started out with MacOS, but there one some strange completion behaviour with the `bash` shell (compared to OpenSuse Linux with tcsh where I come from) that is bugging me:

For example, when I am in $HOME and write Pu on the command line, followed by tabbing for completion, I expected that one of the options shown would be my Public/ directory. However, as long as there are executable files, the completion never shows directories that share the same prefix. Only after entering Publ, the tab completion gives me Public/ as there are no more executables with that prefix.

So my question would be, is there an option to have the completion directly show executables and directories with the given prefix?

I already tried upgrading to bash 4 and installing bash-completion via homebrew but that did not help. I suspect that either the MacOS readline behaves differently or that there are some more setting for .inputrc which I do not know about.

I further know that by starting with ./ I only get directories. This is the bandaid that I use at the moment.

Comment: Did you try pressing the `Tab` button twice? That will show a list of completions as far as I am aware.

Comment: Yes, I did. I will add this to the initial question to clarify.

Comment: On my Mac running Mavericks, `zsh` is behaving as you describe, but `bash` find directly directories and executables at first. Could you add within your question: which shell you are using, and the output of `ls -ld Pu*`?

Comment: I specified that I used `bash` in the question. The output of the ls is just the `Public/` folder. The executables starting with `Pu` are in some directories of the `PATH`. You actually explained the behaviour nicely in your answer and I could verify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most shells with a file expansion function what is expanded in `argv[0]` position is an executable found within one of the directories of the PATH variable.

If you want to find directories when entered as 1st argument within `bash` or `zsh`, simply modify `PATH` as follows:

```
PATH=${PATH}:.
```

and test it with:

`Pub`<kbd>tab</kbd>

For `tcsh` the equivalent modification of PATH is obtained with:

```
setenv PATH ${PATH}:.
```

### Warning

To include `.` into the `PATH` variable is a security risk.
Since this modification any file in the directory where you are will be found as a standard command. This might lead you to execute files you
would never had tried to execute otherwise: executables which will cause a
core dump in a development directory, or binaries which will make you
execute commands to get priviledged access to your system.

This risk is the same for any Unix like OS.

Comment: Thank you. I just checked on my old PC at University and there the default `PATH` actually contained the `.` - so that was the reason why the completion worked different there.
But regarding your warning, I won't add it back and get used to using `./` if I want paths in my completion.
Thank you.

Comment: Wise and secure move :).

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, it's a feature, not a bug.

you could just change to `tcsh`, [here is a guide](http://osxdaily.com/2007/02/27/how-to-change-from-bash-to-tcsh-shell/) (eventually you have to install it via homebrew, then adapt the path)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not know that it was considered to be a feature - or at least one that cannot be disabled.

I might give `tcsh` another try, but I actually wanted to switch to something that is more widely used.

Comment: Oh.. OK but you may try to set bash options (`shopt` shell options) to get that working....

Answer (score -3):

Try it with 
./Pub[tab]

the ./ makes it the current directory to start the tab-completions from

(I'd like to know know how this isn't usefull, as it works that way on Linux too?)

Comment: I guess it is because I already mentioned this option in my question. But it is a valid point and I should probably state this more clearly in my initial question.